# jQuery and IE7 not playing nice

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I can't see what is the problem with his chunk of code but for some reason IE7 is giving me a hard time about it

```
$('.vote').live('click', function() {

        var post_url = base_url + 'ajax_vote' ;
        var mask_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var btn = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    post_url,
            data:   "mask_id=" + mask_id,
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                if( msg == 'pass' ){
                    get_votes(mask_id);
                    btn.replaceWith('<span class="success">Thanks for voting</span>');
                }
                else{
                    btn.replaceWith('<span class="error">You have already voted for this.</span>');
                }
            });

        return false;
    });
```

Can anyone see what I've done to make it complain. Running jQuery 1.6.2 and this sits within an active lightbox hence the .live

Comment: Define "giving me a hard time "

Comment: Sorry, it's just killing the rest of the script so nothing else will work.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you checked for JS errors in the page?

Comment: what is the exactly problem ???

Comment: The only error that its bringing up is line 12 char 4 - if( msg == 'pass' ){

Comment: `.done()` in ajax... never seen before! May be it is `.success()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters avoid [`.live()`](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on) if possible.

Now for your problem:

```
// this doesn't do what you think.
.done(function( msg ) {
```

You should use the [success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of `.ajax()`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. Changed it to the ajax success and it worked like a dream.